# How to use the given convolutional network in an Inception v3 model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I have a code (using keras application with tensorflow backend in python) with the following convolutional layers given below. I wish to apply the same properties in my inception v3 model but do not know how to do so.

I tried creating a regular base model of my inception v3 and apply the properties to it but obtain an error (don't know if it's a code error or not)

```
#CNN based keras application
X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = np.array(pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb")))

# normalizing data 
X = X/255.0

# Building the model
model = Sequential()
# 4 convolutional layers

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
# The output layer with 6 neurons, for 6 classes
model.add(Dense(6))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
# Compiling the model using some basic parameters
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.6, nesterov=True)# Saving the model
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file :
json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

model.save('CNN.model')
```

I wish to apply the same properties as in my CNN model to my inceptionv3 model and save it. Since V3 also takes input from imagenet I also want to know how to take pre trained model into my data as input

Comment: What do you mean by "apply the same properties as in my CNN"?

Comment: @ Matias Valdenegro sorry I made a mistake in conveying what I want. I would like to apply the same convolutional operations (filters) in my inception v3 model